# how to solve Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported

Tags: npm, import

I'm building a NestJS application
I need to validate a type of a file, and im using 'file-type' npm lib
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

But, when start the nest application i receive
{path to my build service}
const file_type_1 = require("file-type");
^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /nest/node_modules/file-type/index.js from /nest/dist/upload/upload.service.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /nest/dist/upload/upload.service.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

In my service, the import is
import { fileTypeFromBuffer } from 'file-type';

I tried to import by another way
Like:
import * as fileType from 'file-type';

And i receive the same error

Answer (score 1):

I tried different versions of the library. file-type@16.5.4 is the latest version
that works and doesn't give the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem huy19th says it right. I tested it and it works.